# Can someone verify my answers to these questions regarding this poset?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, computer-science, relations

**Problem:**
18. Answer these questions for the poset
 ({{1}, {2}, {4}, {1,2}, {1,4}, {2,4}, {3,4},{1,3,4}, {2,3,4}}, $\subseteq$)
$\quad$a.Find the maximal elements
$\quad$b.Find the minimal elements
$\quad$c.Is there a greatest element
$\quad$d.Is there a least element
$\quad$e.Find all upper bounds of {{2}, {4}} 
$\quad$f.Find the least upper bound of {{2}, {4}}, if it exists 
$\quad$g.Find the all lower bounds of {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} 
$\quad$h.Find the greatest lower bound of {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}, if it exists

**My Work**
$\quad$a.Maximal elements are {1, 3,  4} and {2, 3, 4}.
$\quad$b.Minimal elements are {1}, {4}, {2}
$\quad$c.There  is no  greatest element 
$\quad$d.There  is no least element 
$\quad$e.Upper bounds of {{2},{4}} are {{2,4}, {2,3,4}} 
$\quad$f.Least upper bound of {{2},{4}} is {2,4} 
$\quad$g.Lower bounds of {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} are {{3,4},{1},{4}} 
$\quad$h.Greatest lower bound of  {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} is {3,4}

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (a) you missed the maximal element $\{1,2\}$. In (g) $\{1\}$ is not a lower bound of $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{2,3,4\}$: it’s not a subset of the latter. Your answer to (h) is correct, but it’s inconsistent with your (incorrect) answer to (g), since $\{1\}\nsubseteq\{3,4\}$. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Yeah i think i made the mistake on {1,2} because I drew {1,3, 4} above it in my Hasse Diagram. Is the key just going through all the possible path until you can't go up anymore?

Comment: @committedandroider: If the partial order is small enough for you to draw the entire Hasse diagram, that’s the easiest way to do it, yes: look for the elements with nothing above them.